# Grails forms, nested map

Tags: html, grails

I am trying to add another layer of nesting to a Map I have in a Grails command object/form.  The command object currently has a Map called otherData.

```
Map otherData
```

A form has fields with the naming conventions shown below which when submitted produces the Map.

```
<input id="birthDate" name="otheData[birthDate]" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="county" name="otheData[county]" type="hidden" value="">
```

Then in my controller upon form submission I bind it to another map if there is any data to perform a search.

```
if(otherData) {
    _searchCriteria.otherData = otherData
}
```

I basically want to have another layer of inderiction so I could check another key path and perform the correct operation on the data.  Example below:

```
if(searchCriteria otherData.relativeDate) {
    ....
} else if(searchCriteria otherData.absoluteDate) {
    ....
}
```

I have tried to code name of the input to represent a nested map but it isn't creating a nested map in my controller.

```
<input id="birthDate" name="otheData[relative:[birthDate]]" type="hidden" value="">
```

It is producing a map with the keypath

```
otherData.relative:[birthDate
```

Is there any way to add another layer to the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"otheData.relative.birthDate"` instead of `otheData[relative:[birthDate]]`

Comment: it is as explained above, although that would typically bind either into a nested validation object that contains thous items or a reference to otherData as a Map (not tested 3rd layer) but typically you would have either the domain model / object model to bind to it. Try `println params` in the controller to see what is coming back - and also `println params.'otheData.relative.birthDate'`

Comment: if I had a collection at the other end for lets say `fruits` fruits[0]=apple,fruits[1]=orange etc would be my collection coming back as a list and I would receive a params of fruits twice and bound to a list if i am collecting it that way

Comment: Thanks, the params print produces the following: correct form that is working at this point otherData[keyOne]:valueOne AND incorrect form that is not working now otherData.relative.birthDate:testValue

Comment: It looks like the value is always being interpreted as :value so we'll need to have the name be able to accommodate that.